# C++ streams / class template / instance

Tags: class, templates, stream, instance

I'm a new C++ student and having hard time understanding steam input/output.

I'm actually learning from a book, and I found below lines which confuse me.

"The iostream library provides many templates for handling common I/O operations. For example, class template basic_ostream supports stream-output operations..."

So does this mean basic_ostream is defined as:

```
template <class basic_ostream>
```

In the next section, I see lines "Predefined object cout is an ostream instance and is said to be "connected to" the standard output device, which usually is the display screen."

So based on above statements, I would assume below is correct.

```
template <class basic_ostream>

class ostream {
    basic_ostream cout ( "some value" );
}
```

This is confusing me much because in the later chapter, the book starts to discussing put function as...

```
cout.put('A');
```

This mean cout is actually a class object, not an instance of a class.
Am I just confusing the definition of 'instance?'
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template parameters involved deal with the type of character that's read from/written to the stream.

cout (and cin, cerr, clog) are something like:

```
namespace std { 
    basic_ostream<char> cout;
    basic_ostream<char> cerr;
    basic_ostream<char> clog;
    basic_istream<char> cin;
}
```

There are also versions that read and write wide characters:

```
namespace std {
    basic_ostream<wchar_t> wcout;
    basic_ostream<wchar_t> wcerr;
    basic_ostream<wchar_t> wclog;
    basic_istream<wchar_t> wcin;
}
```

So, each of these standard streams is an instance of a class, where the class is an instantiation of a template over a character type that's read from/written to that stream.

For what it's worth, one other point: there's another type called `std::ios_base::Init` that creates these instances before `main` starts executing, and destroys them sometime after `main` finishes executing.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response! ;) I'm still not grasping the concept. So, there would be a class, which handles stream, within 'namespace std{},' and within that class, cout, cerr, clog, and cin are presented? or are you saying cout, cerr, clog, and cin are classes themselves? If so, why is there no 'class' keyword?

Comment: @GrinNare: No--cin, cout, clog, and cerr are objects--instances of classes.

Comment: So... cout will be the object of class basic_ostream which takes in char or wchar_t value? Am I correct?

Comment: @GrinNare: Sorry--stupid thinko on my part--post had misleading information. `cout` is an object of class `basic_ostream` instantiated over `char`. `wcout` is essentially the same, but instantiated over `wchar_t` (wide characters).

Comment: I actually have one more question. Where is this 'stream' stored in? Is it saved in stack or heap? So... user > keyboard > stream in stack (or heap) > cin reads > program???

Comment: The stream object contains a stream_buffer object. So what normally happens is that the program reads a semi-large chunk of data from a file, and stores it in the stream buffer object, then reads smaller pieces (e.g., individual words or characters) from there for use by the program. The actual storage in the stream_buffer object will normally be allocated on the heap.

Comment: A HA! thank you very very much! I will dig more into the stream_buffer object. This was a great help! ;)))